# Counting two cells with a formula, with each containing a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have to make a sum of two totals and print this out in a cell but the sum returns **#VALUE!** when either cell is empty (when both cells contain a number, it works fine).

The sums are as follows:

- ***Sum 1:* =ALS(SOM(G6:G8)=0;"";(SOM(G6:G8)))**
- ***Sum 2:* =ALS(SOM(G15:G17)=0;"";(SOM(G15:G17)))**

Sum 1 is in G9 and Sum 2 in G18.

- ***Sum 3:* =ALS((G9+G18)=0;"";(G9+G18))** < This one counts Sum 1 +Sum 2 returns **#VALUE!**

On a side note: We're using the **Dutch** version of Excel, so

- *=ALS* is *=IF*
- *SOM* is *SUM*

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. SUM1 does indeed go into G9 and SUM2 goes into G18. I'll try out your method now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the SUM function to perform addition in this instance, rather than "+", since the former ignores text values within the range:

=ALS(SOM(G9;G18)=0;"";SOM(G9;G18))

Regards

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue. To think such an easy fix would be hard to find.